# Can I call a function while another is automatically getting called in the backgroud every 5 sec?

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript file that every 5 seconds make a POST request to a flask REST API, that returns me some JSON. Now without interrupting this function can I call other functions without problems?
**My actual Code:**

```
let textValues = {};
let json_Response;
function processForm(form){
    let inputs = form.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(let x = 0; x < inputs.length; x++){
        if(inputs[x].type != "text"){
            continue;
        }
        textValues[inputs[x].name] = inputs[x].value;
    }
    checkUser();
}

function checkUser(){
    let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/User"
    req.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(req.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
            if(json_Response !== req.responseText){
                json_Response = req.responseText;
            }else{}
        }
    }
    req.open("POST", url);
    req.responseType("json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    req.send(JSON.stringify(textValues));
}

function hypotetical(){
    //Call this one
}

window.setInterval(checkUser,5000);
```

Comment: Yes. That's the whole point of an interval - it runs as if it was a background task. Have you tried?

Comment: If you wanna make sure that you're not blocking the browser, i suggest using something like the [Web Workers API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

Comment: *"...every 5 seconds make a POST request to a flask REST API..."* I hope your page/app's bandwidth consumption is clearly disclosed to your visitors/users. On an unmetered connection that's probably no big deal, but a **lot** of people have metered connections (for instance, mobile data plans)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now without interrupting this function can I call other functions without problems?

You can call other functions, and they won't *interrupt* that function, but they may briefly delay a call to it. It shouldn't be a problem.

JavaScript in browsers has only a single main thread,¹ so when your `checkUser` function is actively running, no other functions can run (well, unless `checkUser` calls them); and when you're actively running some other function, `checkUser` can't run (unless that other function calls it). (The timer callback will wait until it can be run.)

Note that `checkUser` only runs ***very*** briefly, starting the ajax request. Then it returns and other things can happen. *Later*, when the ajax request completes, the callback function within `checkUser` runs (very briefly).

So unless you have other functions that will run for many tens of seconds at a time, you don't need to worry about conflicts. (And even then, all it means is that `checkUser` may be slightly delayed.)

---

¹ You can create other threads in their own isolated environments via [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers). Workers can send messages to and receive messages from the main UI thread.